# Access Azure Datalake from Datafactory using Service Principal

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

We are trying to access datalake from datafactory using Service principal.
So as part of it, i created an AD Group and a Service principal. Added the SP to the AD Group.
Used the AD Group to create ACL Roles in the Azure datalake. But this does not work as we get 'This request is not authorized' error.
If i add the ServicePrincipal to 'Storage Blob Contributor' RBAC it works.
Any idea on how to get this working. TIA.

Comment: *If i add the ServicePrincipal to 'Storage Blob Contributor' RBAC **it works.***  |  What is your issue here?

Comment: My issue is i don't want to give the RBAC but add the SP to the AD Group which has been added to ACL to the datalake folders.

Comment: You have to give both.  RBAC grants interaction with the Data Lake and the ACL grants interaction with the files/blobs/etc.  You need both to access/edit the contents of the Data Lake.

Comment: But there are ServicePrincipals which are added only to AAD groups which have access only at ACL levels at the Datalake (no RBAC roles given) folders which are working fine in SSIS.
I tried doing the same for datafactory but it does not work. Unfortunately i am not able to share any screenshots..

Answer (score 0):

Role assignments are used by Azure RBAC to apply sets of permissions to security principals. A security principal is an Azure Active Directory object that represents a user, group, service principal, or managed identity (AD). A permission set can grant a security principal "coarse-grain" access to all of the data in a storage account or all of the data in a container, for example.
Storage Blob Data Contributor, owner or Reader roles.

ACLs allow you to apply the degree of access to directories and files at "Finner Grain." A permission construct containing a sequence of ACL entries is known as an ACL. Each ACL entry links a security principle to a certain access level. See Access control lists (ACLs) in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 for additional information.

Hence, you require to set both the access.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did check with MS and they offered the below.

You will have to use Managed Identity when you use ADLS Storage and Firewall. An alternative would be to install a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime machine. Note: Only Managed Identity authentication is supported when using ‘Trusted Service’ functionality in storage to allow Azure Data Factory to access its data. 
So when i did this, i was able to use the SP to connect to ADL without giving any RBAC but only add to ACL.